# How do i get the status code of a HTTP response when using HTTP Utilities in FSharp.Data

Tags: f#-data

Can't seem to figure out how to get the StatusCode of the HTTP response using the HTTP utilities in FSharp.Data. I am calling HTTP.RequestDetailed, but can't seem to get at the StatusCode of the response.

Answer (score 1):

In FSharp.Data 2.0, the `Http.Request` method also returns the StatusCode: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/reference/fsharp-data-httpresponse.html